# Mapbox - Can I use the locationlistener without Mapbox map

Tags: java, android, location, mapbox, locationlistener

I know the way to use `locationListener` and triggering the GPS is done like that:

```
mapboxMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

I want to open the `locationListener` at app start, but I don't want to use the map in the `startActivity`. Just using the `locationListener` without map.

How can I do with Mapbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an instance of `LocationEngine` to acquire location updates without showing the map.

```
final LocationEngine locationEngine = new LostLocationEngine(this);
locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(new LocationEngineListener() {
  @Override
  public void onConnected() {
    locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

  }
});
locationEngine.activate();
```

Make sure that once you finish getting the location information needed or your activity gets destroyed you remove all listeners, stop requesting updates and deactivate the engine.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it need to handle the location provider by myself, not use the mapbox' logic.

Comment: I don't understand? You mention in a different comment that you wanted to use a Mapbox Tool to do this. The location engine doesn't require any map related code, it's completely independent.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is no! You cannot do it and I recommend you should not do it as it will increase your apk size a lot. If you just need the location listener, there're a lot of libraries which can do it for you as: [Smart Location Library](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib):

```
SmartLocation.with(context).location()
.start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() { ... });
```

Comment: thanks for answer, because I use mapbox map at other activity so I just want to find a way to use the same tool to provide the location